# PHP get Unique value in function and pass it to view file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I am using html5 player.  I want to set multiple players on the same page for that i need to pass a unique value for player id.

To achieve this i have to wrap the player code in a php function called **player()** :

```
public function player() {
    return rand(1,1000);   
}
```

above function will return random number everytime.

In my player code i have to return that value like this:

```
<script>

player.id = <?php echo $playerclass->player(); ?>; // for ex:which returns 120 

player.container= <?php echo $playerclass->player();?> //for ex: which returns 450

</script>
```

Here for container the value should be same as id. If player id value is 120 then player.container value should be same.  If both value will be same then only player will work.

If i keep fixed value like `player.id= 100;` and `player.container= 100;` then it will work for only one player.

For multiple player i have to pass a dynamic parameter.

Is there any way i can achieve this using php or javascript?

Is there any way i can have multiple players with id?

How can i get same value for player.id and player.container at same time for 1 instance?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php already provides a way to generate unique id. How about this.

```
id = <?php echo uniqid(); ?>;
player.container = id;
player.id = id;
```

**The other way**
Also if you want to code a much simpler id, you can just use an increment variable.

```
<?php 
 $id = 1;
 public function player(&$id) {
   return $id++;
 }
?>
```

And then you can just simply use it

```
 player.id = <?php echo $playerclass->player($id); ?>;
 player.container = player.id;
```

Comment: What's the use of this &$id   as argument?  what will it do? This function is in class so how can i keep it dynamic?  Which property i should define?

Comment: @jack the ampersand is [Passing an argument by reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
player.id = <?php echo $playerclass->player(); ?>;
player.container= player.id;
```

Or even simpler, define them both at once

```
player.container = player.id = <?php echo $playerclass->player(); ?>;
```

Comment: Can we do that way?  Both value should be independent.  that way tit's not working.  player.id already have  someother values with it.  if i alert it before the player.container it shows:  player_data_id_120 if i append it container that it will be same while for container it appends different data.  So that way we can not use it.  Is there better way to keep it dynamic through php or javascript?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the following; What do you mean by "keep it dynamic" and whether or not you want the id and container properties to be the same number?